# duda con el signo de exclamacion en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo este codigo pero que significa el signo de exclamacion

```
if(!nombre){

console.error('invalido')}
```

como se llama este operador , no estoy seguro si significa  que si la variable nombre esta vacia entraria en el if o si esta null? se que la usan mucha para no tener que usar el else

Comment: Recuerda que siempre puedes leer [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). Ahí encontrarás muchas respuestas. Por cierto, sugiero que veas [The Javascript Survival Guide](https://youtu.be/9emXNzqCKyg).

Answer (score 6):

El símbolo **!** es lo que se conoce como "Logical NOT operator".

Link a documentación:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

Al hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(!nombre){
//...
}
```

Solo entrará al if en el caso de que nombre sea **false o falsy**, documentación sobre Falsy:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

**Todo lo que no sea Falsy será Truthy.**

Ejemplos:

```
!true //retorna false
!false //retorna true
```

Si existe una variable nombre, lo que podría ser tu caso, podría ser algo así:

```
const nombre = ""

if(!nombre){
console.log("No ha ingresado nombre..")
}
```

En este caso entraría al if porque un string vacío es falsy, sería como decir "si no hay nombre", o "si nombre no está definido" entra al if y hace tal cosa, el caso contrario sería el siguiente:

```
const nombre = "Pedro"

if(!nombre){
console.log("No ha ingresado nombre..")
}
```

En este caso no entraría al if porque un string que no está vació no es falsy, por lo tanto es truthy.

---

**Para terminar de cerrar la idea dejo las siguientes notas:**

```
const nombre = "Pedro" // truthy

!nombre // Sería NOT truthy, o sea que sería falsy.
```

El if lleva una condición que puede ser evaluada como **verdadero** o **falso**. Por ejemplo **a === b**, si son iguales será true, sino será false.

Entonces si se hace:

```
if(true){
    console.log("No ha ingresado nombre..")
}
```

Entraría al if.

Pero si se hace:

```
if(false){
    console.log("No ha ingresado nombre..")
}
```

No entraría al if.

Answer (score 1):

Ese operador significa negación, se utiliza para negar un booleano, si tú le mandas un **TRUE**, regresará **FALSE**, y viceversa.
Generalmente dentro de los if, se suelen utilizar condicionales que den un resultado booleano, para saber si se entrará o no al if, pero hay otras situaciones en las que puedes comparar, por ejemplo, en tu caso, parece que está buscando si nombre tiene un valor, pues cuando utilizas un if, una string vacía (""), se representa como un false, así como el número 0, entre otras cosas. 
Así que tomando todo esto en cuenta, tu código, simplemente revisa, si Negación de Nombre (si nombre tiene una cadena vacía, esta se interpretaría como un FALSE, y ese signo de exclamación lo volvería TRUE, haciendo que entre a el if), imprímeme inválido.